# how to fix Android Annotations 4.6.0 compile with android Studio 3.5 and 3.5.0 gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-annotations

I updated Android studio to 3.5 but there is a problem when I use android annotations

```
Gradle may disable incremental compilation as the following annotation processors are not incremental: jetified-androidannotations-4.6.0.jar (org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.6.0).
Consider setting the experimental feature flag android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in the gradle.properties file to run annotation processing in a separate task and make compilation incremental
```

I've put android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in the gradle.properties file

[image: Here is a Gradel app]
[image: Here is a Grade build]

but it's say that

INFO: The option setting 'android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'false'.

Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had almost the same problem and couldn't build my app after updating android studio and gradle to 3.5 but according to [this answer](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/2191#issuecomment-454318147) I added this to my defaultConfig{} in app gradle and problem solved!

```
javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = [
                    "androidManifestFile": "$projectDir/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml".toString()
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: It worked. Hopefully once AA fixes the issue we can get rid of it

Answer (score 3):

There is 2 way of fixing this issue

**Method One - Use Snapshot version**

Current Annotation lib version is 4.6, to fix these error temporary you can use a Snapshot version

add the following URL in Project-level Gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }

}
```

**Method Two - Use javaCompileOptions**

Add following code in gradle DSL

```
  defaultConfig {
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = ["resourcePackageName": android.defaultConfig.applicationId]
            arguments = ["androidManifestFile": "$projectDir/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml".toString()]
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

AndroidAnnotations does not support [Gradle incremental annotation processing](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/docs/userguide/java_plugin.adoc#incremental-annotation-processing), yet. You can still build your app, it only means that incremental compilation time is not as fast as it could be. There is an [issue](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/2193) for tracking the implementation of incremental processing.

I suggest not to set `android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing` flag, as it is experimental, can cause other issues, and will slow down your clean builds.

Comment: Thanks!, I solve it by downgrade the gradel to 3.4.0 and in gradle-wrapper.properties file To : intdistributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions  TO  "gradle-5.1.1-all.zip "